# Debian Live Installer doesn't see m.2 NVMe SSD

Tags: linux, debian, motherboard, debian-wheezy

I'm trying to install LinuxCNC onto a brand-new machine that has no OS installed. It's got a 128 GB NVMe m.2 card in it that the BIOS recognizes,  but the installer only ever shows the USB Flash stick an available destination.

It's a Gigabyte Z370N WIFI motherboard.

Comment: When running Debian live (or another live linux), can anything else see the SSD? Does it show up in `/dev`? Is it only the installer that can't find it?

Comment: Debian Live (the current LinuxCNC version) never gets fully through the boot process. I'm trying the latest download of Debian to see if it's any different.

Comment: That's a problem... getting it running live might take a special boot code (nomodeset, etc) and might solve the installer problem too.

Comment: The current Debian 9 netinstall was able to recognize the drive. The LinuxCNC is linuxcnc-2.7-wheezy.iso.

Comment: Looks like LinuxCNC uses Debian 7 (wheezy - old-old stable?) as a base, it's got instructions on installing from there, I'll post an answer

Comment: I found instructions for installing LinuxCNC on Debian 9, I was going to try that, although I would like to figure out how to get an older Debian to install, because I want to eventually grab a different LinuxCNC package, and I think that's on 2.7, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the [LinuxCNC documentation](http://linuxcnc.org/docs/html/getting-started/getting-linuxcnc.html#_install_problems) says

> **6. Install Problems**
>
> In rare cases you might have to reset the BIOS to default settings if during the Live CD install it cannot recognize the hard drive during the boot up.

---

Or more specifically about using Debian's net install, the documentation for [Getting LinuxCNC - 7.1. Installing on Debian Wheezy (with Preempt-RT kernel)](http://linuxcnc.org/docs/2.7/html/getting-started/getting-linuxcnc.html#_installing_on_debian_wheezy_with_preempt_rt_kernel)  says you can install from Debian Wheezy (7) net install by doing this:

1. Make a Debian wheezy (7) install usb/cd/dvd (Not debian 8 or 9)
2. Install Debian wheezy
3. Run the following in a terminal to bring the machine up to date with the latest packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
4. Install the Preempt-RT kernel and modules

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-image-rt-amd64
   or
   sudo apt-get install linux-image-rt-686-pae
   ```
5. Reboot, and select the Linux 3.2.0-4-rt-686-pae kernel. When you log in, verify that `PREEMPT RT`is reported by the following command.

   ```
   uname -v
   ```
6. Open Applications Menu > System > Synaptic Package Manager search for linux-image and right click on linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae and select Mark for Complete Removal. Do the same for linux-image-686-pae. Reboot.
7. Add the LinuxCNC Archive Signing Key to your apt keyring by running

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 3cb9fd148f374fef
   ```
8. Add a the apt repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://linuxcnc.org/ wheezy base 2.7-uspace"
   ```
9. Update the package list from linuxcnc.org

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
10. Install uspace (a reboot may be required prior to installing uspace)

    ```
    sudo apt-get install linuxcnc-uspace
    ```

Comment: This was a brand-new motherboard (two, in fact). I did try resetting the BIOS settings. The first motherboard wouldn't even boot from the USB Stick without enabling CSM (the second had it enabled). In the end I installed Debian 9 and followed [these instructions](https://forum.linuxcnc.org/9-installing-linuxcnc/34892-installing-linuxcnc-on-debian-9). Debian 9 was able to recognize the drive.

Comment: I accepted this answer because even though I didn't try it, it's very similar to what I did for the Debian 9 installation, and it explains how to install LinuxCNC for Debian 7. Thank you.

Comment: That's probably even better, I suspect Debian 7 isn't supported anymore (or won't be soon) so the current Debian stable is better to install anyway (especially if the system's online). Hopefully they'll update their documentation soon, looks like the linuxcnc repository supports stretch / 9

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if Tormach's PathPilot is still stuck on wheezy/7.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I did find a little more info about [*Extended* Long Term Support for Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Extended), so 7 Wheezy still has updates until May 2019, at least for some packages that sponsors/customers want, but all users can get the updates.